# How ccan i make webparts appear side by side in SPD 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer

What do i need to set to have my wepart side by side on a webpart page?
    In 2007 there was a setting side by side.I can't find it in 2010

Tried this

```
                <WebPartPages:WebPartZone id="g_EC37749FEC824E8A8B68EFCBB5E591B3" runat="server" title="loc:Right" orientation="Horizontal">
</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

But it doesn't work,
THanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

The orientation tag should work. Here is a picture of the properties to a web part zone.

[image]

And the code looks like:

```
WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" 
Title="loc:RightColumn" ID="RightColumn" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" Orientation="Horizontal"
```

Comment: The OP's code has already set Orientation to Horizontal (which would logically be side by side).